# What is the best heat and moisture resistant adhesive?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, design, adhesive

I have to join metal to metal (Aluminium or SS piece onto a vertical SS wall) that could take a shear load of say, 600gm with an area of contact of around 2cm^2. The environment is above boiling surface of water. So, the adhesive should be resistant to 100 deg C temperature, and moisture - with water droplets. Check the image for setup. **What are the best adhesives for this purpose?** I have checked Araldite, but specs say its max temp is around 65 deg C. Any suggestions? Also desirable is if the adhesive is semi-permanent: If I need to remove it and make the joining at any other location, it shouldn't be terribly difficult.
[image: Setup]

Comment: Rivets or weld it ...

Comment: Why cant you use machine screws, ( with high temp silicone rubber adhesive to seal the threads) ?

Comment: Screws are an option, but I wouldn't prefer it since the location of joining may change in the future, leaving the existing screw hole open; and I wouldn't want the SS tank to be machined every time. I was hoping to find more of a temporary joining.

Comment: No big deal then, if you have to move it in the future you can plug the old (unused) holes with set screws with a little silicone rubber adhesive on the threads.

Comment: Or if you want to be fancy, make your L-bracket with slots in it and have threaded studs mounted in the side of the enclosure, now you can bolt your bracket anywhere within the line-length of the slots.

Comment: For future reference, adhesives.org is a great resource for this type of question.  Search for 'methylmethacrylate adhesive' for an alternative to epoxies in harsh environments.

Comment: JB weld might be a bit too permanent. I'd experiment with 3M 4200 or 5200. The specs say working temp range up to 88C, above that and strength is compromised. But the starting value is 100kg/cm^2 for 4200, 25kg/cm^2 for 5200, so you can afford to loose a bit of strength. This stuff is pretty tough to clean off, but doable from mill finished SS. Easier from passivated and polished SS.

Comment: Would it be an option to clamp the bracket with some kind of magnet onto the casing? You could place a second magnet on the outside to improve the clamping

Comment: That configuration  will want to peel the adhesive. Not good.

Comment: @Martin You would have to keep the magnet cool

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at high temp RTV silicone adhesives. They can handle temps way above 100c. Typically found and used as make-a-gasket material on engines and commonly found at automotive stores.

Also, I'd like to see you use SS for the bracket to keep your thermal expansion co-efficient the same as the base part..I know it's not a lot of temperature change but it may help.

Lastly, I second the fasteners method per the comments because you will have a captured connection between the two parts.

Answer (score 0):

Both products below claim a temperature resistance up to $500^o$, and are water-resistant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JBWeld make the best high temperature adhesive
It can be messy and inconvenient to have to mix, but well worth the time and effort if you want lasting results.
AutoZone Employee